# Is it possible to call generic object constructor using reflection in swift?

Tags: swift, reflection

let's say we have a class

```
class Test: NSObject {
    
    let batman: String
    let spiderman: Int
    let superman: NSObject
    
    init(batman: String, spiderman: Int, superman: NSObject) {
        self.batman = batman
        self.spiderman = spiderman
        self.superman = superman
    }
}
```

And a generic method for initialization:

```
func resolve<T: NSObject>(args: Any...) throws -> T  {
        // if let object = initWithReflectionSomeHow(T.className, arg1, arg2...) {
        //     return object
        // } else {
        //     throw exception
        // }
    }
```

I found a way to to this without parameters like this:

```
func resolve<T: NSObject>() throws -> T  {
        if let objectClass = NSClassFromString(T.className) as? T.Type {
            let object = objectClass.init()
            return object
        } else {
            //throw classNotFoundException
        }
    }
```

So I would just call:

```
let obj = try resolve() as Test
```

but not sure how I can inject parameters. Is it even possible?

Comment: If you can call `resolve` already, why don't you just initialise the object directly?

Comment: @Sweeper because object can have other dependencies that `resolve` can take care of. for example if you want to init a viewController with viewModel that depends on some services `resolve` would also create those services and viewModel and inject those in viewController. Without that you would have to do all of this manually every time and everywhere you need that viewController.

Comment: Use a Coordinator class instead that can handle all view model instantiation etc

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I could do that technically but I'm trying to create a container based custom Dependency Injection class that takes advantage of reflection for object initialization. if that's possible obviously.

Comment: If there are multiple inits (e.g `initWithSomething:` `initWithSomething2:`) in the `NSObject` subclass with same number of arguments how would you choose the appropriate one?

Comment: @Kamil.S maybe by parameter names? or types? not sure. It can be done in C# by parameter names. So I was wondering if swift had the capability